# undercores with collection name in hibernate

Tags: hibernate

```
Hibernate: insert into college (name, college_id) values (?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into student (college_id, student_name, student_id) values (?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into student (college_id, student_name, student_id) values (?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: select college0_.college_id as college1_1_0_, college0_.name as name1_0_ from college college0_ where college0_.college_id=?
Hibernate: select students0_.college_id as college2_1_0_, students0_.student_name as student3_0_ from student students0_ where students0_.college_id=?
```

I am new to hibernate.while selecting a row from a table from mysql db i am getting the above console statements.In that (college0_.college_id as college1_1_0_ ) what is college0,college1_1_0_ .I didn't understand what is 1_1_0 and table name college with 0 concatanating.

Any one explain me.Thank you

Comment: They're just [aliases](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alias_(SQL)).

Comment: @Robby i know they are aliases i am asking what is this pattern 1_1_0

Comment: It's Hibernate's dynamic alias generation at work. It's just an implementation detail.

Comment: @Robby it will take table_row_column like this?

Comment: [This article](https://prismoskills.appspot.com/lessons/Hibernate/Chapter_23_-_Hibernate_alias_names.jsp) explains it.